# Why i can't connect to my mysql with user "Root” but others can

Tags: mysql

For example
There are two same users like:

```
Root
Gelbooru
```

when i use command

```
mysql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -u Root -p
```

and enter the correct password ,it return :

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'Root'@'yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy' (using password: YES)
```

the ip 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is the server i want to connect and 'yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy' is the server which i use this command.

then i create a new user 'Gelbooru' and it has the same privilege and white-list.
i use the same command but use new user to connect to the server 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' and it works!

use command

```
select User,Host from mysql.user;
```

and get

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select User,Host from mysql.user;
+----------+-----------+
| User     | Host      |
+----------+-----------+
| Gelbooru | %         |
| Root     | %         |
| root     | 127.0.0.1 |
+----------+-----------+
```

by the way. i can use the user 'Root' with navicat and any function works well.

can someone tell me why it happens and how to solve it...
thanks anyway

Comment: Post the output of `select User,Host from mysql.user;` I suspect you dont have a host wildcard setup for the root user

Comment: are you sure it is `Root` and not `root` ? The latter is way more probable

Comment: @Paras i already edit the question..and the host of these two users is all '%'

Comment: then its probably an issue of a **wrong password**

Comment: @Nanne yeah i sure about that. i also have a user 'root' but can only login on locahost  ,i think mysql run at linux is case sensitive

Comment: @Paras but that can't explain I can use Navicat to connect to that server use the user 'Root'

Comment: did you try to type the password in your terminal? maybe you have a different charset/locale/whatever, and any special characters come out wrong?

Comment: @Nanne my password only have numbers and characters.and i also try copy/paste and it doesn't work....

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a user root@'%' as given below:

```
create user root@'%' identified by <PASSWORD>;
```

Comment: i use 'Root' and it is @'%'